# One page with two menus, but when scrolling the area of the second menu, it is not showing the menu item as active

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I used jQuery-One-Page-Nav for a one page scrolling menu.  In my page there are two menus on either side of a logo. So, I have to use jQuery-One-Page-Nav twice.  If I click any menu, it scrolls this area and shows the menu button for the current page as active. But when I scroll to any area of the second menu, the menu button for the active page in that menu is not being activated.

Here is the link to jQuery-One-Page-Nav: [jQuery-One-Page-Nav](https://github.com/davist11/jQuery-One-Page-Nav).

[Here, I have attached an image. Please click to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0W8ym.png).

Please give some solutions for this problem.

Here is my code:

```
  /*ONE page menu one*/
        $('#nav').onePageNav({
          currentClass: 'current',
          scrollOffset: 75
        });

  /*ONE page menu two*/
        $('#mav').onePageNav({
           currentClass: 'current',
           scrollOffset: 75
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two navbars for that page. You didn't post your code, but if you are using `li` then give the first left three `li` a class identifer and give the second right three a class identifier and then use `css` to position them using `float: left` and `float: right`.

If you are using bootstrap then you may use `navbar-left` and `navbar-right` classes.